# creating rotating circle using characters |, /, \,- in shell script

Tags: shell

I want to write a shell script which does installation related task. I want to show some icon like rotating circle by printing characters  |, /, \, -. Once the installation completes this circle will disappear. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted solution is overly complicated.  You can just do:

```
while sleep 1; do 
  i=$((++i%4 + 2)); 
  printf '\b|/-\' | cut -b 1,$i | tr -d '\n';
done
```

(Note that subsecond sleeping is not portable, and neither is seq.)

Comment: Thank you. Its great. I need to try this solution and will understand how it works once I am free from my meeting.

Answer (score 4):

Building on Marc B's answer, here's a simple demo:

```
spin () {

  chars="| / – \\"

  rotations=3

  delay=0.1

  for i in `seq 0 $rotations`; do

    for char in $chars; do 

      echo -ne $char
      sleep $delay
      echo -ne '\b'

    done

  done

}
```

Paste it in your terminal and type 'spin'.

---

Update: this version works in both bash and zsh.

```
spin () {

  char=( \| / – \\ )

  charLastIndex=3

  rotations=3

  delay=0.1

  for i in `seq 1 $rotations`; do

    for j in `seq 0 $charLastIndex`; do 

      echo -n ${char[$j]}
      sleep $delay
      echo -ne '\b'

    done

  done

}
```

---

Update: liori's version works in multiple shells.

```
spin () {
  rotations=3
  delay=0.1
  for i in `seq 0 $rotations`; do
    for char in '|' '/' '-' '\'; do
      #'# inserted to correct broken syntax highlighting
      echo -n $char
      sleep $delay
      printf "\b"
    done
  done
}
```

Comment: @liori, do you know of a way to get echo to behave in zsh, or a workaround? It seems to be including part of the prompt after the echo.

Comment: Hmm, zsh doesn't like space as a field separator either.

Comment: Seems that in zsh to do field splitting on unquoted variables you need to set SH_WORD_SPLIT option (see `man zshparam` or `man zshoptions`), e.g. by `setopt -o SH_WORD_SPLIT`.

Comment: Also, `dash` doesn't understand `echo -e`. But `dash` accepts `\b` without `-e`. Same with `posh`, which is a shell written to be as close to POSIX as possible.

Comment: @liori I see what you mean about dash... and it doesn't like the second version at all. Surely there's a way to do this that all these shells will accept, without doing a bunch of ugly checks and branching.

Comment: This works under all four shells: http://pastebin.com/jQ3in67B. Feel free to put it into your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo -e 'abc\bd'
            ^^---backspace char
```

will output

```
abd
```

So basically you'd output one of your animation chars, then output a backspace, then output the next char, etc...

Comment: You need the `-e` option to `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is **POSIX shell compliant** version:

```
while true; do for x in '|' '/' '-' '\'; do printf '\b$x'; sleep 1; done; done
```

Note that as side effect your value of `x` will be overridden. To avoid this enclose instructions into function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't specify which shell, a little plug for the [fish shell](https://fishshell.com/), where this can be done quite elegantly using arrays:

```
set -l symbols ◷ ◶ ◵ ◴
while sleep 0.5
    echo -e -n "\b$symbols[1]"
    set -l symbols $symbols[2..-1] $symbols[1]
end
```

In this case, `symbols` is an array variable, and the contents if it are rotated/shifted, because `$symbols[2..-1]` are all entries but the first.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the answer of @gavenkoa, there should be double quotes around the variable expansion, this way we should get a primitive but working POSIX compliant spinner:

```
while true; do for x in '|' '/' '-' '\'; do printf "\b$x"; sleep 1; done; done
```

(This might not be worth a separate answer, but I'm not yet allowed to comment, and when trying to edit the old answer, it says the edit queue is full.)